# Docker compose from a yml postgres database url error

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Docker .yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  pg_tileserv:
    image: pramsey/pg_tileserv
    ports:
      - "7800:7800"
    environment:
       - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:correctpassword@ipaddress:5432/dbname
```

I run

```
docker-compose -f pg_compose.yml up --remove-orphans
```

and I get this error

```
Removing orphan container "map_httpd_1"
Starting map_pg_tileserv_1 ... done
Attaching to map_pg_tileserv_1
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=info msg="pg_tileserv latest"
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=info msg="Run with --help parameter for commandline options"
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=info msg="Using database connection info from environment variable DATABASE_URL"
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=info msg="Serving HTTP  at http://0.0.0.0:7800/"
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=info msg="Serving HTTPS at http://0.0.0.0:7801/"
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=info msg="Using CoordinateSystem.SRID 3857 with bounds [-2.00375083427892e+07, -2.00375083427892e+07, 2.00375083427892e+07, 2.00375083427892e+07]"
pg_tileserv_1  | time="2021-08-27T14:59:36Z" level=fatal msg="cannot parse `postgresql://postgres:correctpassword@ipaddres:5432/dbname`: failed to parse as URL (parse \"postgresql://postgres:dbname\": invalid port \":dbname\" after host)"
map_pg_tileserv_1 exited with code 1
```

BUT If i ran that command to connect to another DB it sets up and works fine

and even stranger if I run it this way it works and properly sets up the container!

```
docker run -e PGUSER=postgres -e PGPASSWORD=correctpassword -e PGHOST=ipaddress -e PGPORT=5432 -e PGDATABASE=dbname -p 7800:7800 pramsey/pg_tileserv
```

I have no idea why the .yml file is giving me an error

the real password has a # in it

Comment: What are the real values ? Do they contain special characters like `:` or `@` ?

Comment: the password has a # in it

Comment: Try to split the enviroments like you did in the docker run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/jackc/pgconn/blob/master/config.go#L387):

The `pramsey/pg_tileserv` will finally call `jackc/pgconn` which use `net/url` to parse your `DATABASE_URL`:

```
url, err := url.Parse(connString)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

if url.User != nil {
    settings["user"] = url.User.Username()
    if password, present := url.User.Password(); present {
        settings["password"] = password
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `#` in url is treat as anchor which should be encoded before call `url.Parse`. So, for you, manually encoded the `#` before set the value to `DATABASE_URL` is your workaround.

From [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/), the `#`'s hex is `23`, so if your password is `password#`, you should change it to `password%23`.

Then, if the full connecting string is next:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password#@ipaddress:5432/dbname
```

You should change it to:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:password%23@ipaddress:5432/dbname
```

Of course, if you have other special html character, e.g. space, then you should also change it to `%20` according to ASCII table, and so on...